# Getting max free ID available in postgresql for int8

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with few IDs say 100000, 99999, 99998, 1000, 10, 5. Now my requirement is to get max ID which is not used.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES (10000),(9999),(9998),(100),(5),(2) )
    AS t(id);
```

In above case, it should be 99997. Any query to get this max available ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used lead() function to get difference between current id and next id on descending order.

```
with ct as
(
    select id, lead(id) over (order by id desc) as nextid
    from foo
)
select   id -1 as next_id
from     ct
where    id - nextid > 1
order by id desc
limit 1;

next_id
-------
 9997

drop table foo;
```

Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/VSXA67194)

Comment: Thanks McNets! It gave expected result!

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Comment: You need an `ORDER BY id DESC` in the outer select as well, for the query to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `left join`:

```
select t.id - 1
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.id = tprev.id + 1
where tprev.id is null
order by t.id desc
limit 1;
```

Another uses `lag()`:

```
select t.id - 1
from (select t.*, lag(id) over (order by id) as prev_id
      from t
     ) t
where prev_id <> id - 1
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: when I execute ur lag query it shows 1 in result. Is anything missing here?

Comment: @Fahmina . . . Yes, something was wrong.  I fixed it.